# ¿Alta cohesión en desarrollo?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, html5, poo

¿Que se toma como alta cohesión? por ejemplo la clase persona, la cual esta enfocada a un objetivo, otro caso seria que los atributos fueran dirigidos a otro objetivo, que tiene relación con persona.

```
public class Persona {

    //Primer objetivo de la clase
    private String nombre;
    private String aPaterno;
    private String aMaterno;
    private int edad;

    //Segundo objetivo de la clase
    //Datos Fiscales
    private String RFC;
    private String moral;
    private String fisica;
    private String compañia;
    private String domFiscal;


    /**
     * @return the rFC
     */
    public String getRFC() {
        return RFC;
    }
    /**
     * @param rFC the rFC to set
     */
    public void setRFC(String rFC) {
        RFC = rFC;
    }
    /**
     * @return the moral
     */
    public String getMoral() {
        return moral;
    }
    /**
     * @param moral the moral to set
     */
    public void setMoral(String moral) {
        this.moral = moral;
    }
    /**
     * @return the fisica
     */
    public String getFisica() {
        return fisica;
    }
    /**
     * @param fisica the fisica to set
     */
    public void setFisica(String fisica) {
        this.fisica = fisica;
    }
    /**
     * @return the compañia
     */
    public String getCompañia() {
        return compañia;
    }
    /**
     * @param compañia the compañia to set
     */
    public void setCompañia(String compañia) {
        this.compañia = compañia;
    }
    /**
     * @return the domFiscal
     */
    public String getDomFiscal() {
        return domFiscal;
    }
    /**
     * @param domFiscal the domFiscal to set
     */
    public void setDomFiscal(String domFiscal) {
        this.domFiscal = domFiscal;
    }
    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    /**
     * @return the aPaterno
     */
    public String getaPaterno() {
        return aPaterno;
    }
    /**
     * @param aPaterno the aPaterno to set
     */
    public void setaPaterno(String aPaterno) {
        this.aPaterno = aPaterno;
    }
    /**
     * @return the aMaterno
     */
    public String getaMaterno() {
        return aMaterno;
    }
    /**
     * @param aMaterno the aMaterno to set
     */
    public void setaMaterno(String aMaterno) {
        this.aMaterno = aMaterno;
    }
    /**
     * @return the edad
     */
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
    /**
     * @param edad the edad to set
     */
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola, ¿que es exactamente lo que necesitas?, ¿estas pidiendo alguna opinión o cual es el problema?

Comment: No tengo claro a qué te refieres. ¿Sabes cuál es la expresión en inglés?

Comment: Que tal, si trato de pedir opiniones sobre la interpretación de la alta cohesión, soy algo nuevo en el uso de desarrollo en capas, lo que entiendo es que esta ligado al bajo acoplamiento, "high cohesion low coupling".

Comment: Según el centro de ayuda en [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) las preguntas basadas en opiniones son consideradas irrelevantes para el sitio, ten cuidado.

Comment: Muy bien seguiré investigando, gracias.

Comment: Alta cohesión significa que la clase debe solo una cosa, está ligado al principio de responsabilidas única (single respinsability). En tu ejemplo, la clase debería representar únicamente a los datos de una persona, lo del rfc iría en otra clase.

Comment: Gracias @Luis, tambien encontre un par de blogs, https://juan-garcia-carmona.blogspot.com/2012/09/grasp-alta-cohesion-y-bajo-acoplamiento.html     https://apiumhub.com/es/tech-blog-barcelona/principios-solid/